# Creating an object based on a result set

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I have a question regarding an object that is created based on a `ResultSet`.

Let's say I have a product DAO class:

```
public class ProductDAO
{    
    ...
    ResultSet products = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT ");  

    if (products .next()) {   
       int prodId = products .getInt("id");           
       String prodName = products .getString("name");    
       Product product =  new Product(prodId, prodName);       
    }          
    ...
}
```

Let's say the SQL query returns 5 rows. As a result, what would the product object finally contain? Would it only contain the values of finally returned row (in this case the 5th row)?

Comment: You need to create array of `object` of `Product` class and then use  `while` loop (`while(products.next())`) to retrieve the data from database into your object.

Answer (score 2):

If your query fetches more than one row, you should have a loop and create multiple Product instances. Your current code would only read the first row and create a single Product instance.

Here's a better implementation that would load all the data returned by the query:

```
List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
while (products.next()) {   
   int prodId = products .getInt("id");           
   String prodName = products .getString("name");    

   Product product =  new Product(prodId, prodName);       
   productList.add(product);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eran, I too felt the same way, but why do you say a single Product instance from the first row? Shouldn't it be the last row? cos I thought the 'next' method will traverse till the last row returned and a Product instance will be created based on this last row. I am not sure if I am getting this right, what I mean is a Product instance of 'product' is being created for each row, only to be 'overiden' by the next iteration of the loop, till the final row is reached.

Comment: @Sor Since you are only calling the `next()` method once, it makes the ResultSet point to the first returned row. Each call to `next()` moves the ResultSet to the next row. You have no loop in your code. You have an if statement. My suggested code has a loop. If you had a loop, the product reference would be overwritten in each iteration.